# Why is there free space at the end of NTFS Partitioned Drives?

Tags: linux, windows, ntfs

I've been wondering this for a while, why is there free space at the end of a drive that was formatted to NTFS in windows?

You can only see the unallocated space in Linux. So why is it there? Does it serve a purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Acronis (https://kb.acronis.com/content/1884)

> 1. Up to 7.8 MB (minimum of 1MB) of unallocated space resides at the end of the hard disk. This area is reserved by Windows operating systems for the purpose of creation of Dynamic Disk structures. This unallocated space area is not shown in Windows Disk Management; however Acronis Disk Director is able to merge it with an adjacent partition. Therefore, after doing that there can be problems with creating Dynamic Disk structures.
> 2. Exactly 7.8 MB of unallocated space reside at the beginning of the hard disk. Normally this means that there are no Primary partitions on the hard drive and the hard drive contains an Extended partition only. In such cases Windows reserves the minimal amount needed for creating a partition (7.8 MB) in order to be able to handle the only Extended partition properly. It is not recommended to remove this area. Even though technically it is possible to merge it with the Extended partition, this may result in the data on it becoming inaccessible.